# Annotation.toString() omits double quotes from String attributes

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How can I print the value of an Annotation's field with double quotes when it's a String?
For instance:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface MyAnnotation {
    String myField();
}

@MyAnnotation(myField = "bla")
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Annotation annotation : Test.class.getAnnotations()) {
            System.out.println(annotation);
        }
    }

}
```

The code above produces:

```
@MyAnnotation(myField=bla)
```

How can I change it to produce `@MyAnnotation(myField="bla")`?

Comment: Print it yourself.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sounds great, but how would you do that?! The Annotation interface does **not** provide any means to access the internals required to do such printing. That thing just has toString() to offer!

Comment: Are you trying to reconstruct source code? Why are you trying to do this? What does it matter how it prints?

Comment: The only thing you could possibly do here is something reflective, which will be painful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I need it because I'm extending and compiling a class at runtime and that class doesn't inherits annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is the only way:

```
for (Annotation annotation : Test.class.getAnnotations()) {
    System.out.println(toString(annotation));
}

private String toString(Annotation annotation) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Object> paramValues = getParamValues(annotation);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("@")
            .append(annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName())
            .append("(");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : paramValues.entrySet()) {
        result.append(param.getKey()).append("=\"").append(param.getValue()).append("\", ");
    }
    result.delete(result.length() - 2, result.length());
    return result.append(")").toString();
}

private Map<String, Object> getParamValues(Annotation annotation) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        for (Method param : annotation.annotationType().getMethods()) {
            if (param.getDeclaringClass() == annotation.annotationType()) { //this filters out built-in methods, like hashCode etc
                params.put(param.getName(), param.invoke(annotation));
            }
        }
        return params;
}
```

This will print exactly what you asked for, for any annotation on any class (you'll just have to see how you want to print non-string attributes).

But... why would you ever need this?

Comment: Thanks, kaqqao. That works! I need it because I'm extending and compiling a class at runtime and that class doesn't inherits annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The [Annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) interface doesn't provide any insights into the specific annotation. But I think you can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (Annotation annotation : Test.class.getAnnotations()) {
    if (annotation instanceof MyAnnotation) {
       ... then you can cast to that specific type ...
       ... and then access/print 
    }
}
```

Normally such instanceof checks with downcasts should be avoided, but I don't see a way to solve your problem without doing so.

Comment: I can't do it because the method which will print the annotation doesn't know MyAnnotation or Test.

Comment: Then I dont know how to help. Unless you want to use **reflection** to look into those Annotations, and to do "printing" based on what you can discover using reflection.